# Excel VBA - looking for a faster search / match function

Tags: excel, xml, vba, search

I have created a VBA workbook that tabulates XML attributes/settings. I then use it to compare two version of the configurations (many XML files) and show me the differences. Generating the tag list only takes a minute or two, but comparing the configs takes over an hour. A config has about 30,000 XML tags.

Full code is shown below, but the basic summary is:

- Create list of XML tags and their attributes from config 1
- Copy tags and attributes to Compare worksheet
- Create list of XML tags and their attributes from config 2
- Search the Compare worksheet for each tag XPath from Config 2

  - If you find a match, copy the attributes from Config 2 to the matched line in Compare (next set of columns)
  - If you don't find a match, add a new line to the Compare worksheet.

I've loaded the second config into an array, which should have made it faster; thanks to stackoverflow: [Faster Find Method and filter position comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265919/faster-find-method-and-filter-position-comparison)

Any other hints on how to speed this compare function up? I need to run it several times a day, and I'd rather not need to wait an hour each time (especially as I can't use the computer while it's running).

```
Sub Compare(Optional Silent As Boolean)

    Dim Compare_Path_2 As String

    Worksheets("Compare").Range("A4:BY4").ClearContents
    Worksheets("Compare").Range("A5:DM1048576").ClearContents

    ApplicationCalculationPrev = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


    If Not Range("Reprocess_Last_Generated_TagList").Value Then
        Compare_Step = "1. Processing TagList of Config 1 = " & SiteName
        Config_1_Name = Range("Compare_SiteName_1").Value
        Range("SiteName") = Config_1_Name
        Call ListFilesInFolder(Range("Compare_Path_1").Value, False, True)
    Else
        Compare_Step = "1. Reusing last TagList of Config 1 = " & Config_1_Name
    End If 'Reprocess_Last_Generated_TagList
    
    TagList_LastRow = Worksheets("TagList").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Row
    
    Compare_Step = "2. Copy TagList of Config 1 = " & Config_1_Name & " to Compare_StartCell"
    Worksheets("TagList").Range("A4:AN" & TagList_LastRow).Copy Destination:=Range("Compare_StartCell")


    Config_2_Name = Range("Compare_SiteName_2").Value
    Range("SiteName") = Config_2_Name

    Compare_Path_2 = Range("Compare_Path_2").Value
    If Right(Compare_Path_2, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
        Compare_Step = "3. Loading already processed taglist of " & Compare_Path_2
        'Compare_Path_2 could be an already processed taglist
        Workbooks.Open Compare_Path_2
        Compare_WorkBook_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        For Each Sheet In Workbooks(Compare_WorkBook_2).Worksheets
            If UCase(Sheet.Name) = "TAGLIST" Then
                GoTo TagListFound
            End If
        Next Sheet
    
        MsgBoxResponse = MsgBox("Sheet TagList not found in target workbook " & Compare_Path_2, vbCritical)
        Stop
    
TagListFound:
        Workbooks(Compare_WorkBook_2).Worksheets("TagList").Activate
    
        'Need to validate that the TagList has data and it is in the correct format.
        TagList_Valid = True
        TagList_Invalid_Reason = ""
        If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count < 2 Then
            TagList_Valid = False 'Sheet is empty or only has header
            TagList_Invalid_Reason = TagList_Invalid_Reason & vbCr & "Sheet is empty or only has header."
        End If
        If Left(ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value, 2) <> "//" Then
            TagList_Valid = False  'Column B is not in XPath format
            TagList_Invalid_Reason = TagList_Invalid_Reason & vbCr & "Column B is not in XPath format."
        End If
    
        For ColumnCount = 1 To 41
            ThisWorkBookHeader = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TagList").Cells(3, ColumnCount).Value
            TargetWorkBookHeader = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, ColumnCount).Value
            If TargetWorkBookHeader <> ThisWorkBookHeader Then
                TagList_Valid = False  'Column headers for TagList don't match
                TagList_Invalid_Reason = TagList_Invalid_Reason & vbCr & "Column " & ColumnCount & " headers don't match: ThisWorkBookHeader  = " & ThisWorkBookHeader & ", TargetWorkBookHeader = " & TargetWorkBookHeader
            End If
        Next ColumnCount
        '... may need to put more validators here
    
        If Not TagList_Valid Then
            Message = "TagList of target does not match expected format, please regenerate using this builder." & TagList_Invalid_Reason
            Call Syslog("Compare", 1, "Error", Message, True, True)
            MsgBoxResponse = MsgBox(Message, vbCritical)
            Stop
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TagList").Range("A4:BA1048576").ClearContents
            Workbooks(Compare_WorkBook_2).Worksheets("TagList").Range("A4:AJ1048576").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TagList").Range("A4")
        End If
    Else    'Right(Compare_Path_2, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
        Compare_Step = "3. Generating Taglist of Compare_Path_2 = " & Compare_Path_2
        Call ListFilesInFolder(Compare_Path_2, False, True)
    End If



'******************************************************************************************
'******************************************************************************************
Compare:

    Call LogMessage(1, "Compare_Configs - Start Compare Find between " + Config_1_Name + " and " + Config_2_Name)
    Compare_Step = "4. Starting Compare"
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Copy second config to target
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets("TagList").Activate

    'Clear the filters. Worksheets("TagList").ShowAllData Throws an error if there is no filter currently applied
    On Error Resume Next
    If Worksheets("TagList").AutoFilterMode Then Worksheets("TagList").ShowAllData
    If Worksheets("Compare").AutoFilterMode Then Worksheets("Compare").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    SourceLastRow = Worksheets("TagList").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Row
    TargetLastRow = Worksheets("Compare").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Row
    Worksheets("Compare").Range("DL4:DL" & TargetLastRow).Value = True  'Pre-load Only In Config 1 with True - will be over-written if a tag is found.
    Worksheets("Compare").Range("DM4:DM" & TargetLastRow).Value = False 'Only In Config 2

    FirstRow = True


    'Can't just copy second config, need to match the tags up in case there are tags missing
    '2013-04-24 New method per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265919/faster-find-method-and-filter-position-comparison
    'Load search into array to make it faster.

    Dim wks_TagList As Worksheet
    Dim SourceArray As Variant
    Dim TargetArray As Variant
    Dim TargetArrayFilter As Variant
    Dim SourceArrayIndex As Long
    Dim TargetArrayIndex As Long
    'Make doubles!

    'For Each Cell In Worksheets("TagList").Range("B4", Cells(SourceLastRow, 2))
    Compare_Step = "5. Sort TagList"
    Worksheets("TagList").Activate
    Worksheets("TagList").Range("A3:AN" & SourceLastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("B3"), Header:=xlYes, order1:=xlAscending
    SourceArray = Worksheets("TagList").Range("A4", Cells(SourceLastRow, 40))
    'Range("B3", Cells(TargetLastRow, 2)).Select


    Worksheets("Compare").Activate
    Worksheets("Compare").Range("A:DM").EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Have a macro to hide columns that don't have any differences - make sure all columns are showing.
    'To Clear All Fitlers use the ShowAllData method for for the sheet.  Add error handling to bypass error if no filters are applied.  Does not work for Tables.
    On Error Resume Next
        Worksheets("Compare").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    Compare_Step = "6. Sort Compare"
    Worksheets("Compare").Range("A4:DM" & TargetLastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("B3"), Header:=xlYes, order1:=xlAscending
    'TargetArray = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Compare").Range("B4", Cells(TargetLastRow, 2))) 'Need to transpose to get proper 1D array? Ref Mr Excel search Filter causes Mismatch
    'StartIndex = LBound(TargetArray)
    'EndIndex = UBound(TargetArray)

    'With wks_TagList
    'SourceLastRow = UBound(SourceArray)


    Compare_Step = "7. Match tags"
    For SourceArrayIndex = LBound(SourceArray) To UBound(SourceArray)
        
        tagName = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 2)
        SourceRow = SourceArrayIndex + 3 'TagList starts on Row 4, SourceArray starts at 1
        
        Dim LogMessageString As String
        If SourceArrayIndex Mod 1000 = 0 Or FirstRow Then
            Progress = Format(100 * (SourceArrayIndex / SourceLastRow), "0")
            LogMessageString = ConfigName + " Comparing line " & SourceArrayIndex & " of " & SourceLastRow & " (" & Progress & "%), tag = " & tagName
            Call LogMessage(3, LogMessageString, True)
        End If
        If SourceArrayIndex Mod 100 = 0 Or FirstRow Then
            Progress = Format(100 * (SourceArrayIndex / SourceLastRow), "0")
            Application.StatusBar = ConfigName + " Comparing line " & SourceArrayIndex & " of " & SourceLastRow & " (" & Progress & "%), tag = " & tagName
            FirstRow = False
            StopCheck '======================================================================================================= StopCheck
        End If
        
        Compare_Method_Search = True
        
'        If Not Compare_Method_Search Then 'Old method - Loop through TargetArray
'            For TargetArrayIndex = StartIndex To EndIndex
'
'                If TargetArray(TargetArrayIndex, 1) = tagName Then
'                    '2023-04-04 Speed enhancement idea:
'                    '   Found a match. Both arrays were sorted alphabetically, so we know we do'nt have to search above this line next time.
'                    StartIndex = TargetArrayIndex
'
'                    'Found a match, copy values across
'                    TargetRow = TargetArrayIndex + 3
'                    Worksheets("TagList").Activate
'                    'Worksheets("TagList").Range(Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 5), Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 34)).Select
'                    'Worksheets("TagList").Range(Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 34)).Select
'                    'Worksheets("TagList").Range(Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 5), Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 34)).Copy 'Destination:=Worksheets("Compare").Range(Cells(TargetRow, 37))
'                    Worksheets("TagList").Range(Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 5), Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 34)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 37)
'
'                    Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 116).Value = False  'Only In Config 1
'                    Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 117).Value = False  'Only In Config 2
'                    'Stop Searching
'                    GoTo Found
'                End If 'If TargetArray(TargetArrayIndex, 1) = TagName Then
'
'            Next 'For TargetArrayIndex = LBound(SourceArray) To UBound(SourceArray)
'
'            'If we make it here, Tag was not found, add it to the end of Compare
'            TargetRow = Worksheets("Compare").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Row + 1
'            'TargetRow = SourceArrayIndex + 3
'            Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 1).Value = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 1) 'FileName
'            Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 2).Value = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 2)  'Tag XPath
'            Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 3).Value = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 3)  'Tag DotPath
'            Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 4).Value = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 4)  'Type
'            Worksheets("TagList").Activate
'            Worksheets("TagList").Range(Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 5), Cells(SourceArrayIndex + 3, 39)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 42)
'
'
'            Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 116).Value = False  'Only In Config 1
'            Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 117).Value = True   'Only In Config 2
'
'
'        Else    'Compare_Method_Search
            'New method - search array instead of loop and check.
            'TargetArrayFilter = Filter(TargetArray, tagName, True, vbTextCompare)
            Set FoundCell = Worksheets("Compare").Range("B4:B" & TargetLastRow).Find(tagName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            
'            If UBound(TargetArrayFilter) > -1 Then 'tagName was found in TargetArrayFilter - copy data to matched row
'                'TargetArrayFilter is only 1 row - need to find where it is in original array?
'            Else    'tagName was not found in TargetArrayFilter - need to addd new tag to end of compare sheet.
'            End If  'UBound(TargetARrayFilter) > -1
            
            If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                'Search failed, new tag was not in original list. Add to end of list
                'If we make it here, Tag was not found, add it to the end of Compare
                TargetRow = Worksheets("Compare").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Row + 1
                'TargetRow = SourceArrayIndex + 3
                Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 1).Value = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 1) 'FileName
                Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 2).Value = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 2)  'Tag XPath
                Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 3).Value = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 3)  'Tag DotPath
                Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 4).Value = SourceArray(SourceArrayIndex, 4)  'Type
                'Worksheets("TagList").Activate
                'Worksheets("TagList").Range(Cells(SourceRow, 5), Cells(SourceRow, 34)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 37)
                
                Range(Sheets("TagList").Cells(SourceRow, 5), Sheets("TagList").Cells(SourceRow, 39)).Copy
                Worksheets("Compare").Range("AP" & TargetRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        
        
                Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 116).Value = False  'Only In Config 1
                Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 117).Value = True   'Only In Config 2
            Else
                'Search found the new tag in the original list, populate new attributes.
                TargetRow = FoundCell.EntireRow.Row
                
             '   Debug.Print "Compare: Matched " & tagName & " with " & FoundCell.Value & " on row " & TargetRow
                'LogMessageString = "Compare: Matched " & tagName & " with " & FoundCell.Value
                'Call LogMessage(3, LogMessageString, True)
                
                If StepCode Then
                    Sheets("TagList").Activate
                    Range(Sheets("TagList").Cells(SourceRow, 5), Sheets("TagList").Cells(SourceRow, 39)).Activate
                    Range(Sheets("TagList").Cells(SourceRow, 5), Sheets("TagList").Cells(SourceRow, 39)).Select
                End If
                Range(Sheets("TagList").Cells(SourceRow, 5), Sheets("TagList").Cells(SourceRow, 39)).Copy
                
                If StepCode Then
                    Worksheets("Compare").Activate
                    Worksheets("Compare").Range("B" & TargetRow).Select
                    Worksheets("Compare").Range("AP" & TargetRow).Activate
                End If
                Worksheets("Compare").Range("AP" & TargetRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                
                'If TargetRow Mod 20 = 0 Then Stop
                Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 116).Value = False  'Only In Config 1
                Worksheets("Compare").Cells(TargetRow, 117).Value = False  'Only In Config 2
            
            End If
            
'        End If 'Compare_Method_Search
        
Found:
    Next 'SourceArrayIndex = LBound(SourceArray) To UBound(SourceArray)
    
    Compare_Step = "8. Compare complete, fill diff formulae"
    
    Worksheets("Compare").Activate 'Need to activate the sheet before sorting, otherwise it throws an error.
    CompareLastRow = Worksheets("Compare").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Row
    Worksheets("Compare").Range("BZ4:DK" & CompareLastRow).FillDown
    Worksheets("Compare").Range("A3:DM" & CompareLastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("B3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
    Worksheets("Compare").Calculate
    Worksheets("Compare").Activate
    Worksheets("Compare").Range("B3").Select
    Compare_Step = "9. Filter_AnyDiff"
    Call Filter_AnyDiff
    Compare_Step = "10. Hide_NoDiff_Columns"
    Call Sheet4.Hide_NoDiff_Columns
    
    
    
    Application.Calculation = ApplicationCalculationPrev
   
    
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Compare_Step = "11. Complete"
    
    'If IsMissing(Silent) Or Not Silent Then Call MsgBox("Compare Complete", vbOKOnly)

End Sub
```

Test code used to test @Tim's suggestion:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long


Sub Find_Vs_Match_Speed_Test()

    Debug.Print "Find_Vs_Match_Speed_Test started at " & Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS") & Right(Format(Timer, "0.000"), 4)

    Set SourceRange = Worksheets("TagList").Range("B4:B404")
    
    FindStart = GetTickCount
    For Each Cell In SourceRange
        Set FoundCell = Worksheets("Compare").Range("B4:BB29849").Find(Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Next Cell
    FindFinish = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Find method took " & (FindFinish - FindStart) / 1000 & " seconds"
    
    MatchStart = GetTickCount
    For Each Cell In SourceRange
        FoundVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cell.Value, Worksheets("Compare").Range("B4:B29849"), 0)
    Next Cell
    MatchFinsh = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Match method took " & (MatchFinsh - MatchStart) / 1000 & " seconds"
    
    
    Debug.Print "Find_Vs_Match_Speed_Test finished at " & Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS") & Right(Format(Timer, "0.000"), 4)

End Sub
```

Corrected test code: (Thanks again Tim!)

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long


Sub Find_Vs_Match_Speed_Test()

    Debug.Print "Find_Vs_Match_Speed_Test started at " & Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS") & Right(Format(Timer, "0.000"), 4)

    Set SourceRange = Worksheets("TagList").Range("B4:B4004")
    Set SearchRange = Worksheets("Compare").Range("B4:B29849")
    
    FindStart = GetTickCount
    For Each Cell In SourceRange
        Set FoundCell = SearchRange.Find(Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Next Cell
    FindFinish = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Find method took " & (FindFinish - FindStart) / 1000 & " seconds"
    
    MatchStart = GetTickCount
    For Each Cell In SourceRange
        FoundVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cell.Value, SearchRange, 0)
    Next Cell
    MatchFinsh = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print "Match method took " & (MatchFinsh - MatchStart) / 1000 & " seconds"
    
    
    Debug.Print "Find_Vs_Match_Speed_Test finished at " & Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS") & Right(Format(Timer, "0.000"), 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: There's lot of code there but I'd focus on maybe replacing that `Find()` with `Application.Match()`, which is a lot faster.  Also, to make your code more readable, use some variables to refer to the worksheets instead of repeating (eg) `Worksheets("Compare")` over and over.  This reduces the bulk of your code and makes it easier to read.   And stop `Activate`'ing worksheets - there's no reason to do that if you're not relying on implicit sheet references when using (eg) Range/Cellls

Comment: And add `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables.  This is far too much code to be using undeclared varaibles.

Comment: OK, yup, Tim's suggestion is faster... by an order of magnitude of almost 1000 times! I added the test code to the question so it formatted better than in comments, but here's the result!
Find_Vs_Match_Speed_Test started at 18:35:19.590
Find method took 90.813 seconds
Match method took 0.016 seconds
Find_Vs_Match_Speed_Test finished at 18:36:50.420

Comment: FYI your test code is using different ranges for Find (B4:BB29849) vs Match (B4:B29849)...

Comment: Well spotted, thanks! OK, so it's only 100 times faster now... :)  
Find method took 23.36 seconds.  
Match method took 0.234 seconds.